# Weka - loading an arff file, keep getting error @relation expected, but the format is correct

Tags: analytics, weka

I have been trying to load an arff file i have created and i keep getting an error message which is basically false. the body, pasted from notepad++ is as follows:

```
@relation Credit_application

@attribute checking_status real
@attribute credit_amount real
@attribute saving_category real
@attribute employment_category real
@attribute age real
@attribute class real

@data
2,1169,1,5,67,2
3,5951,2,3,22,1
1,2096,2,4,49,2
2,7882,2,4,45,2
2,4870,2,3,53,1
1,9055,1,3,35,2
1,2835,4,5,53,2
3,6948,2,3,35,2
1,3059,5,4,61,2
```

[image: error]

Comment: I made an arff file directly from what you posted above, and had no problems loading it into Weka Explorer.  Your problem is a mystery to me, as well. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: No problem thanks for trying! may just  reinstall weka.

Comment: i never got to the bottom of why but copying and pasting all the content into a new file solved it. very strange indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery was never solved but creating a new identical file eradicated the error message